# Perform For Loop after first instance of condition

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

I have 5 columns of data starting in Row 10:

C: Material
D: Full Cost
E: Saving
F: Invoice Cost
G: Period
H: Reason for No Saving

When no saving has been provided, (i.e. full cost = Invoice Cost), and that Material has already been entered in the same Period, I would like to highlight the cell in Column H to show a reason must be provided.

I understand how to do this using a simple countifs inside a for loop.
Code which highlights cells, but does not exclude first instance of a Material in a Period:

```
For A = 10 To PD.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If PD.Range("H" & A).Value = "" And PD.Range("D" & A).Value = PD.Range("F" & A).Value And _
      WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(PD.Range("C10:C5500"), PD.Range("C" & A).Value, PD.Range("G10:G5500"), PD.Range("G" & A).Value) > 1 Then
      
        PD.Range("H" & A).Interior.Color = RGB(253, 211, 211)
        
    End If
Next A
```

I only want Column H to be highlighted after the first instance of a Material being entered in a given Period Number. I.e. the first time a Material is entered in a Period, there is no need to highlight the Cell in Column H, anytime after in that same Period - the cell should be highlighted.

I think I need to add some kind of Material Variable Counter alongside Period Number to keep track of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the Countifs() range as you move down:

```vb
For A = 10 To pd.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    With pd.Rows(A)
        If .Columns("H").Value = "" And _
           .Columns("D").Value = .Columns("F").Value And _
             Application.CountIfs(pd.Range("C10:C" & A), .Columns("C").Value, _
                                  pd.Range("G10:G" & A), .Columns("G").Value) > 1 Then

            .Columns("H").Interior.Color = RGB(253, 211, 211)

        End If
    End With
Next A
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim FirstSkipped as Boolean
FirstSkipped = False
For A = 10 To PD.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   If FirstSkipped Then
        If PD.Range("H" & A).Value = "" And PD.Range("D" & A).Value = PD.Range("F" & A).Value And _
        WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(PD.Range("C10:C5500"), PD.Range("C" & A).Value, PD.Range("G10:G5500"), PD.Range("G" & A).Value) > 1 Then

            
        PD.Range("H" & A).Interior.Color = RGB(253, 211, 211)
        
        End If
   End if
   FirstSkipped = True
 Next A
```